# Foreach with Extension Method on IEnumerable

Tags: c#, foreach, extension-methods, ienumerable

Quick Question, See this code:

```
List<int> result = new List<int>();

var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

list.Select(value =>
    {
        result.Add(value);//Does not work??
        return value;
    });
```

And :

```
result.Count == 0 //true
```

Why result.Add(value) not executed?

However this not executed, Another question that is have a way do a **foreach** on a **IEnumerable** with **Extention Method**?

Except this way: `IEnumerable.ToList().Foreach(p=>...)`

Comment: @DJKRAZE Its already a delegate.

Comment: I posted my delegate example below to utilzie the list.ForEach

Comment: `ForEach` is not an extension method nor is it LINQ.  `ForEach` is a method on `List<T>`.

Comment: yes but he's using list.Select when he can just use List.ForEach

Comment: Just FYI - In the future, I'd recommend sticking to one question per question/post....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Why result.Add(value) not executed?

This is because LINQ uses deferred execution.  Until you actually enumerate the results (the return of `Select`), the delegates will not execute.

To demonstrate, try the following:

```
List<int> result = new List<int>();

var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

var results = list.Select(value =>
    {
        result.Add(value);//Does not work??
        return value;
    });

foreach(var item in results)
{
     // Just iterating through this will cause the above to execute...
}
```

That being said, this is a **bad idea**.  LINQ queries should not have side effects if you can avoid it.  Think of `Select` as a way to transform your data, not execute code.

> However this not executed, Another question that is have a way do a foreach on a IEnumerable with Extention Method?

You could write your own extension method:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(var item in items)
         action(item);
}
```

However, I would recommend not doing this. For details, refer to [Eric Lippert's post on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answers, your description solved my confusing of understanding IEnumerable and deferred execution.

Answer (score 3):

Select is lazy and the execution is deferred until you start enumerating over the results. You need to consume the resultset by calling .ToArray for example or by looping over the result:

```
list.Select(value =>
    {
        result.Add(value);//Does not work??
        return value;
    }).ToArray();
```

Comment: If I was going to use a method just to force the enumeration I'd go for one with constant memory like `Max()` rather than `ToArray()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<int> result = new List<int>();
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
list.ForEach(delegate(int sValue)
{
    result.Add(sValue);
});
```

This works but all and adds 1 2 3 4 into result. Test it out. I just did.

Comment: I mentioned: Except this way: IEnumerable.ToList().Foreach(p=>...)